# How to get Chromecast + SPDIF Audio Splitter + DTS capable amplifier output 5.1 sound?

Tags: hdmi, nas, chromecast, 5.1, dolbydigital

I have a 1st generation Chromecast, a non-smart Samsung TV (UE40D5000P) and Sony STR-DB840 receiver with 5.1 speakers hooked up. I'd like to enjoy media streamed through Chromecast (from Netflix and from my Synology NAS) with Dolby Digital or DTS sound, so far without success.

Things I have tried:

1. Using the TV's DLNA capabilities, I can play movies directly from the NAS via an Ethernet connection. In this setup, I hook up the receiver via an optical cable to the TV's optical output, and magic happens. I have DTS and Dolby Digital sound on my system. Cons: I can only do this with media stored on my NAS (and even for those I won't have subtitles).
2. I plugin in the Chromecast to one of the 4 HDMI inputs of the TV. I connect the receiver the same way as before to the TV (optical cable). Anything I cast on the TV (from the NAS, from Netflix, from Youtube etc.) will have only stereo sound. The receiver says "PCM (48Khz)" when auto-detecting the audio source.
3. I use an intermediate Toslink audio extractor (SpeaKa Professional 29063c25) between the Chromcast and the TV and receiver. I plug the Chromecast into the input HDMI port of the extractor, I hook up the TV to the output HDMI port of the extractor, I use the same optical cable between the extractor and the receiver, and I set the extractor to 5.1 sound output mode. Results are the same as in 2. (stereo sound, no Dolby).

Is there any way to achieve with my current set of gears what I'd like to?

If not, then what am I missing and what would be the most cost-effective way to upgrade my setup so I can enjoy 5.1 sound?

**UPDATE**: from my TV's manual:

> When the receiver (home theatre) is set to on, you can hear sound
>   output from the TV's optical jack. When the TVis receiving a DTV
>   signal, the TV will send 5.1 CH sound to the home theatre receiver.
>   When the source is a digitalcomponent such as a DVD / Blu-ray player /
>   cable box / STB (Set-Top-Box) satellite receiver and is connected
>   tothe TV via HDMI, only 2 CH audio will be heard from the home theatre
>   receiver. If you want to hear 5.1 CH audio,connect the digital audio
>   out jack from your DVD / Blu-ray player / cable box / STB satellite
>   receiver directly to anamplifier or home theatre

So it seems like what I've described in No. 2. above will never work, as for HDMI inputs the TV can only output 2 CH audio. So the remaining question: using the external audio extractor, is it possible to get the 5.1 sound to the receiver? These audio extractors certainly claim that that is their primary function.

Comment: Is your reciever set to "DIRECT"?

Comment: @varfirstName It's set to A.F.D, which is Auto Format Decoding. And, as I mentioned, the receiver can detect and play 5.1 properly, as described in the first point under "Things I've tried"

Comment: Any luck / new discoveries with your configuration? I'm on the same boat and after unsuccessfully trying solution no. 2, I was about to buy SpeaKa Professional Audio Extractor to try solution no. 3, as there were some positive reports from similar devices on Amazon. Does your Netflix app show you 5.1 surround option when using solution no. 3? Have you decided to try any other approach? Does 5.1 work with another apps? It *should* work, DD+ can be converted to DD, which is passed via Toslink and I thought that was precisely what those devices were supposed to do..

Comment: @tlegutko I gave up with this configuration. I bought one more gadget, an HDMI EDID emulator that can spoof the accepted HDMI formats when placed before an HDMI device. I set it explicitly to sound format 5.1, but even then I couldn't get 5.1 sound from my audio extractor. I think it's all due to the TV stating that it only accepts 2.0 audio, thus limiting audio to 2.0 in the whole HDMI network. I gave up, bought a new receiver with several HDMI inputs, I plugged the Chromecast in one of the inputs, now everything works like a charm.

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi thank you for your answer, I came to the same conclusion - after thoroughly reading Q/A on multiple Amazon products, they all share two problems: 1) EDID signal you mentioned is determined by output hdmi device despite various switches on various devices and 2) none of those extractor devices offers converting DD+ to DD, they either don't support DD+ or just allow it in hdmi-passthrough mode, which is not what we wanted to achieve. only viable solution is to buy a proper receiver with HDMI input.. actually you can submit it as an answer for any other lost souls like us :)

Comment: Can you tell us what receiver you purchased with the multiple HDMI inputs?